# Set web browser URL to textbox contents

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-8, textbox, webbrowser-control

I am making a project that is a Windows 8 app.

I would like to set the url of the web browser element to the contents of the Textbox.

Here is my code although at present it does not work!

```
    Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Webbrowser.Navigate(New Uri(TextBox.Text))

    End Sub
```

This works for my Windows Forms project but not for my W8 project!

**Edit**

[image: Image demonstrates issue I am having]

Image demonstrates error I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text Box was not named! Watching this video meant I discovered my error! [Video Avalible Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPHKSf23FG4)

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox` is the name of the class. Since it doesn't have a `Shared` property named text, it is saying that you need to to get the `Text` property of an instance of the class.

Typically in WinForms, if you drag a textbox onto the form, it'll name it something like `TextBox1`. So you'd want to get the `.Text` property of that specific textbox *instance* like this `TextBox1.Instance`. I'm not entirely sure what your textbox is named in W8.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this for the Navigate button (Go)

```
Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Webbrowser1.Navigate(urlTxtbox.Text)
End Sub
```